# How do you show 2 list view of the same field in form view

Tags: python, odoo, python-3.7, odoo-13

I already make a form view for a model, in this model, I have a one2many field called task_id that is related to project.task, I tried putting task_id in a page called Details, and Summary both of which is using the same task_id field but have a different view, one has less field to show then the other.
but when I tried to make the view, I tried using

```
<field name="task_id">
  <tree>
     <field name="field_name"/>
  </tree>
</field>
```

and

```
<field name="task_id" context="{'tree_view_ref':'module.view_name'}"/>
```

both field always use the same view everytime. I manage to make the view looks different by adding another field for summary that is related to task_id, but is there a way to have 2 different view, show the same one2many field, in 1 form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a `related` field:

```
other_view_task_id = fields.One2many(related="task_id")
```

Then add that to your form view:

```
<field name="other_task_id" context="{'tree_view_ref':'module.view_name'}"/>
```